# What is the adjectival form of "nemesis"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, suffixes, derivational-morphology

If I have a non-person object or idea that I consider to be my nemesis<sup>1</sup>, how could I refer to the object as a noun but use an embellishing adjective to emphasize that the object is my nemesis?

For instance, "Since the end of World War II, Communism has been the [nemesisical] ideology of the United States."

Some words that come to mind include *adversarial*, *opposing*, *antagonistic*, but these don't have quite the same  meaning.

---

<sup>1</sup>This question was prompted by a now-deleted question on Software Engineering.SE: [Do you have a [programming] language that's your nemesis?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53718/do-you-have-a-language-thats-your-nemesis) (10k only)

Comment: *Arch-inimical* would have been nice, but that is hardly a common word. There is also *antithetical*.

Comment: I’ve just brought my citation count for ***nemetic*** up to eight. It’s a fine word.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT**: References provided at the bottom.

---

The short answer is ***nemetic***.  Longer answer follows.

In English, nouns of Greek origin that end in *-esis* regularly form corresponding adjectives that end in *-etic*: *antithesis, antithetic; diuresis, diuretic; emesis,  emetic; genesis, genetic; kinesis, kinetic; mimesis,  mimetic; synthesis, synthetic; tmesis, tmetic.*

Although this is perfectly normal English derivational morphology to coin new words out of existing classical forms, usually the related words already had related terms in that form in the original classical languages. For example, Latin has *synthesis* and *syntheticus*, and Greek *σύνθεσις* and *συνθετικός*; *kinesis* and *kinetic* are from Greek *κίνησις* and *κῑνητικός*.

Sometimes closely related words exist. The noun *tmema* is related to *tmesis* and *tmetic*; the noun *thema, themata* is allied with *thesis*, as is *anathema* (although that’s right from Greek *ἀνάθεμα*).

English also likes to elaborate the *-ic* forms to create new nouns via *-ics*, as in *genetics*, and sometimes also use the *-ic* form to double up the adjectival endings by adding *-al* to the existing *-ic* to form adjectives and nouns, as in *hypothetical, hypotheticals*.

So the adjective related to *nemesis* must necessarily be ***nemetic***. 
Interestingly, the semi-lookalike *Nimetic*™ exists as an expired trademark for a bonding substance used in dental reconstruction.

The OED doesn’t cover proper nouns like that, and ∗*nimesis* is not attested in the *OED*. It also doesn’t list *nemetic.* However, the related terms *nemesism* and its derivative, *nemesistic*, both are. *Nemesism* is ‘frustration and aggression directed against oneself’, and *nemesistic* is the adjective that corresponds to *nemesism*, **not** to *nemesis*.

If for some odd reason you don’t care to use that natural adjectival form ***nemetic***, then you’ll have to return to the definition of *nemesis* and choose a synonym, then rederive a new adjective from that.  The *OED* attests three primary senses of [***nemesis***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125992):

1. a. Usu. in form **Nemesis**. Originally in classical mythology: the goddess of retribution or vengeance, who reverses excessive good fortune, checks presumption, and punishes wrongdoing; (hence) a person who or thing which avenges, punishes, or brings about someone’s downfall; an agent of retribution. [citations from 1542—1989]

   b. orig. and chiefly *N. Amer.* In extended use: a persistent tormentor; a long-standing rival, an arch-enemy. [citations from 1933—2000]
2. a. Usu. in form **Nemesis**. Retributive justice; (also) an instance of this; the downfall brought by it. [citations from 1597—1989]

   b. An unavoidable consequence *of* (or occas. *for*) a specified activity or behaviour; an inevitable penalty or price. [citations from 1863—1991]
3. *Astron*. In form **Nemesis**. A small, faint star postulated as a companion to the sun in a hypothesis to explain the supposed cyclical nature of terrestrial mass extinctions. 
   According to the hypothesis the companion star follows a highly eccentric orbit around the sun which causes it to disturb the Oort cloud every 26 million years, sending a shower of comets into the inner solar system. [citations from 1984—1994]

If you were looking for an adjective corresponding to sense **1b**, you might choose the synonym *arch-enemy*, whence one could perhaps offer up the admittedly awkward *arch-inimical*.  The word *inimical* comes ot us from Latin *inimīcālis*, itself a compound formed by combining *in-* not with *amīcus* friend. In modern parlance, one might think of that as an *unfriend*; indeed, enemy has the same origin, albeit via a more circuitous route, having passed to us from Old French *enemi, anemi, anemy*; compare also modern French *ennemi*,  Provençal *enemie*, Catalan *enemig*, Spanish *enemigo*, Portuguese *inimigo*, Italian *nemico*.

One can use enemy as an adjective: *enemy agent, enemy nation, enemy ships*; Orwell wrote ‘Koestler‥was once again thrown into prison as an enemy alien.’ Used in this way it is stronger than merely *unfriendly*, taking on more of the added connotation of some specific adversary.

However, since you asked for a non-person, that seems to require sense **2b**, not **1b**.  I’m not sure you want to go back to *unfriendly* or *adversarial* here, as the former is too general, while the latter has judicial connotations you may wish to avoid.

Really, I think I’d just go back to my original suggestion of ***nemetic***. If that feels too bizarre to you, than perhaps you could try using *nemesis* attributively. But ***nemetic*** is certainly the natural adjective, so you might as well use it. Other people have certainly done so.

## Citations

- 1972, Scott Gordon, 
  Two Monetary Inquiries in Great Britain: The MacMillan Committee of 1931 and the Radcliffe Committee of 1959; 
  *Journal of Money, Credit and Banking*, Vol. 4, No. 4 (Nov., 1972), page 966 ―     There were, however, strong moralistic overtones to the arguments of those
  who stressed productivity, there being a nonnegligible incidence among them
  of the Blimpish view that the depression was, after all, simply the ***nemetic***
  consequence of personal softness, “living beyond one's means,” and a lack
  of concern for the morrow.
- 1989, Isaac Asimov, *Nemesis* (1989), p 156 ―
  Nemesis will go right through the Solar System and have a perceptible
  effect on several of the planets. .. The ***Nemetic*** System is much smaller
  than the Solar System and therefore is held together more tightly.
- 2002, Kane X.  Faucher;
  Modalities, logic, and the Cabala in Borges’ “The Theme of the Traitor and the Hero”. (Dossier: Borges: perplejidades filosoficas).
  *Variaciones Borges*, July 1, 2002; 
  http://business.highbeam.com/434832/article-1G1-87916115/modalities-logic-and-cabala-borges-theme-traitor-and ―
  For Borges, history is ***nemetic*** – a measure of all history – while the
  particularities or singularities (the people who are affected by the
  repeating events) are anamnetic: the Platonico-Leibnizian doctrine of
  reminiscence.
- 2003, Julian Barnes;
  The seeds of rebellion;
  *The Guardian*, 28 March 2003 ―
  Moralists know that Hubris inevitably leads to Nemesis, but never before
  had the theory been given such literal expression.  .. Why it went wrong we
  ***Nemetics*** never discovered.
- 2004, David Abram, *Goa*, page 146, ―
  Environmental groups and villagers keen to preserve the area's relative tranquillity secretly hope the ***nemetic*** powers of the mysterious old curse will not wane.
- 2009,
  Tim Rifat Interview with Jeff Rense; April 28, 2009;
  http://educate-yourself.org/cn/timrifat28apr09interview.shtml ―
  Obama has been placed into the archetypal template which fits into the
  ***nemetic*** group mind and he is being used as the ultimate thought weapon to
  drive the entire Western group mind into a mob consciousness prior to the
  Ashkenazy neo-Stalinist takeover.
- 2009, Simon Warner;
  Wainwright or wrong? No rock in Rufus opera,
  July 29, 2009,
  http://simonwarner.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/wainwright-or-wrong-rufus-opera-opens-and-closes ―
  a leering and unnerving creation by Jonathan Summers as the
  singer’s domineering mentor, suggestive, in lime green suit,
  of Batman’s ***nemetic*** Joker;
- Steve Mann, Jason Nolan, and Barry Wellman;
  Technomimesis and Sousveillance: Using Technology to Challenge Technosocial Surveillance;
  http://wearcam.org/cyborg_and_community/cyborgandcommunity.0.15short.html ―
  The mimetic act of holding a mirror to the social environment is something
  that Mann moves beyond written narrative to the actual use of similar
  surveillance techniques to “watch the watchers”, and this ability allows
  for the potential taking up of the ***nemetic*** role of “bringer of social
  justice” presented as an act of inquiry.

---

That proves that the standard classical derivational morphology of ***nemetic < nemesis*** is a recognized construct already in use in English, so you might as well use it.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nemetic

Comment: Sorry -- didn't see it

Comment: I'm not planning to use *nemetic* in a sentence any time soon, but +1 for thorough research and argument.

Comment: Wow, you really answered the crap out of that question.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think there's any graceful way to turn nemesis into an adjective, but you might turn it into one all by itself:

> Since the end of World War II, Communism has been the nemesis ideology to the United States.

Or, better, turn it around and make the current noun the adjective:

> Since the end of World War II, Communism has been the ideological nemesis of the United States.

Comment: The latter, just to be certain.

Comment: +1 for the latter.  There may be a grammatical adjective to "nemesis" but I would never use it :)

Comment: I don’t mind your offered workarounds, but why would you say there’s no graceful way to change an *-esis* word into an adjective? That’s just not true.  *-esis* > *-etic*. This is super-basic inflectional morphology.

Comment: @tchrist: Ordinarily that's true (mimesis => mimetic, etc.), but nemesis is derived from a proper name (the Greek goddess Nemesis), and as such is more fixed. Who would understand *nemetic* used in that context?

Comment: @Robusto初夢 Why should proper nouns have a different inflectional morphology? *Timmy > Timmies, Sally > Sallies, Hermes > hermetic, Styx > Stygian, Iris > iridic, Venus > venereal, Eros > erotic, Herperus > Hesperides, Fides > fidelity, Medusa > medusae* (meaning the cnidarian), *Nox > nocturne, Pollux > pollucite.* Clearly, a proper name still inflects normally. As for who would understand *nemetic* in that context, perhaps you should ask that of David Abram, per my citation below. Certainly any of my own friends and colleagues would instantly understand it.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm sure you hang around with an educated crowd who are not a representative sampling of English speakers. I still believe that even most reasonably intelligent people would not understand it readily, if at all.

Comment: @Robusto初夢 I took you up on checking whether ‘most reasonably intelligent would understand it readily, if at all.’ I asked a dozen family, friends, and colleagues if they could figure out what it meant using the Abram citation. Some knew immediately that it was connected to *nemesis*, while others took more time but still less than half a minute; only 3 of them gave up and tried to guess based on context, which they indeed managed. If you grant that my sample set were ‘reasonably intelligent’, then I’ve disproved your thesis. You’ll also see I’ve brought my citation count up to 8 in my answer.

Comment: @tchrist: I just did my own grandmother survey and got results that contradict yours. Shows you the value of small sample sizes. But check out this [NGram comparison](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nemesis%2Cnemetic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of the two. You can see that the usage of *nemetic* is obscure, pedantic, and vanishingly small by comparison with *nemesis*.

Comment: @Robusto初夢 "Pedantic"?  Hello?  Don’t use dem furrin words if you don’t like how they work. I work in the medical sciences doing computational linguistics, and I quite assure you that everyone there knows about *-esis* > *-etic.* It’s very basic to all of them. Some whom I asked weren’t even native English speakers, and they got it, too. It’s true that almost everyone I asked holds advanced degrees, but that also happens to be how my family, friends, and colleagues pan out. It is perfectly representative of that set, as I previously indicated. **Nothing was ever achieved by aiming low.**

Comment: @tchrist: Umm, success in limbo dancing?

Comment: @tchrist +1 for "super-basic"

Answer (score 3):

While a bit clumsy, "nemesis-like" is possible.

Answer (score 3):

A catching point is that *Nemesis* was originally the name of a Greek goddess. While it's no longer considered a proper noun, perhaps its origin lends some clarity as to why it's so difficult to modify. Turning any proper noun into an adjective presents unique problems. Examples (of dubious etymology) convert the word into a verb first, and then participle. For example, see [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Zuckerberged) defines both *Zuckerberged* and *Zuckering*, but doesn't have a definition for *to Zucker* or *to Zuckerberg*.

But just for fun, let's try it:

> Since the end of World War II, Communism has been the *Nemesised* ideology of the United States.

A rephrase makes this slightly easier to accept, in my opinion:

> Since the end of World War II, the United States has *Nemesised* the Communist ideology.

I think you should give up, though, unless you [like to verb words](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/verb-words/).

Comment: Using your point about 'Nemesis' being the name of a Greek Goddess, I suppose we could use 'Nemesisian' in the same way we use 'Dickensian' or 'Orwellian'. (We'll ignore the fact that the latter two terms are accepted by the spell checker while the former one is not.)

Comment: If you do regard it as Greek, the adjective would be "nemetic".  This isn't an answer because I don't approve of such coinages.

Comment: @TimLymington ‘Don’t approve of’ — say **what**?  English morphology mirrors Latin here, which mirrors Greek: *-esis* words always go to *-etic* words. That’s simply how it works in English, and one needn’t be a Greek scholar to know that. The OED attests more than 350 *-esis* words, many of which have related *-etic* forms. Saying you ‘don’t approve’ is just plain silly, like people saying they ‘don’t approve’ of *-y* > *-ies*, or *-c* > *-cking*.  Approval is irrelevant.

Comment: @tchrist: No, I don't approve of making new adjectives from names, particularly when nobody believes in the mythology any more. And it appears that most of the world agrees with me: you have found precisely one printed use.

Comment: @TimLymington I bet you really hate jovial and venereal, don’t you? Sheesh! Anyway, *nemesis* used without a capital is no longer a proper noun, so your objection is irrelevant. Even with a capital, it’s still Nemetic. And I have not found ‘precisely one printed use’! I *cited* one. There are others. For example, Asimov wrote of a Nemetic asteroid (see *Nemesis*, OED sense 3). Another reference is ‘...nemetic consequence of personal softness, "living beyond one's means," and a lack of concern for the morrow’, which you may pursue for yourself. That makes three. There are more. Enjoy.

Comment: @TimLymington I’ve now brought my citation count at the bottom of my answer up to eight: I hope you’re satisfied now that ***nemesis*** cleary becomes ***nemetic***.

Answer (score 1):

A couple words that come to mind are anathema and bane. As examples,

"Since the end of World War II, Communist ideology has been anathema to popular political views in the United States."

or

"Since the end of World War II, Communism has been the bane of political ideology in the United States."

Comment: Aren't these both nouns?