# Achilles' heel or achilles heel? - Is it proper to lowercase the usage

Tags: phrases, capitalization

I was reading [an article](http://gigaom.com/2012/04/09/here-is-why-did-facebook-bought-instagram/) that uses the phrase "Achilles' heel" to refer to Facebook's acquisition of Instagram, but it was written thus:

> achilles heel

My main question is - was this a bad mistake or is making this kind of description in this way a common thing? If so, could you provide examples where others have taken common phrases and lowercased them.

A little more context in case it helps:

> Because Facebook is essentially about photos, and Instagram had found and attacked Facebook’s achilles heel — mobile photo sharing.

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/achilles-heel-and-achilles-tendon

Comment: @tchrist I'd put your comment as the answer on this one. There are examples of eponyms that have "gone native" as it were and lost their capitalization but I'm unable to find solid examples of this one.

Comment: Is this just about the casing used, or is the lack of apostrophe also in question?

Comment: @Alan: ...and even if it isn't, I'd like to read the answer to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Achilles* is a proper noun. However, [this ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Achilles+heel%2Cachilles+heel&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) does seem to show some extremely slight/rare incidence of the lowercase form.

[image: Google Ngram of Achilles heel]

That doesn’t make it “right” or generally accepted.

Comment: While Jon Purdy's answer is sound and absolutely valid, I chose this as the correct answer simply because I've never seen Google Ngram Viewer. Thanks all! Now... about that darn apostrophe... :P

Comment: Can one also prompt Google ngrams to show the trends of apostrophe usage in the compound?

Answer (score 2):

Much like a [genericised trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark), many terms that were originally derived from proper names have evolved over time into ordinary words:

- *quixotic*—[Don **Quixote**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quixote)
- *boolean*—[George **Boole**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole)
- *abelian*—[Niels Henrik **Abel**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Henrik_Abel)
- *chauvinistic*—[Nicolas **Chauvin**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Chauvin)
- *sadistic*—[Donatien Alphonse François, Marquis de **Sade**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquis_de_Sade)
- *erotic*—[**Eros**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eros)

Therefore I would say it’s acceptable to use the lowercase form, *achilles heel*.

Comment: Yes, or [nemetic < Nemesis](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54141/2085), but all of those are adjectives derived from nouns, while *Achilles tendon* uses *Achilles* attributively, so it is still a noun. In similar constructs, the capital seems to stick around.  For example, the *Golgi apparatus* is not yet ∗golgi, either, nor the *Kuiper belt* yet ∗kuiper.  Perhaps someday.

Comment: @tchrist: I have no problem generalising. The capital will depart anyway when the legend is forgotten.

Comment: @tchrist, the difference is that I'm not sure if I've heard of the "Kuiper belt", and I'm quite certain I've never encountered a "Golgi apparatus", whatever the heck that is; whereas *Achilles' heel* is a pretty common phrase. The closest parallel I can think of is *Krebs cycle*, but that seems to be called the *citric acid cycle* nowadays, probably because people want to give credit where it's due to Szent-Györgyi's contributions, but nobody can pronounce Szent-Györgyi (just ask my sister).